# is there a way to port forward two routers?

Tags: networking, router, port, forwarding

i have two routers
Router 1 connected to the network

and Router 2 connects Ethernet to Router 1 and also Ethernet to me

Router 1 is DHCP

and router 2 is also DHCP (Linksys)

so i watched a video on how to port forward two routers

and what he did was to change router 2 to static ip
and putting in router 1 the router 2 static ip
and from router 2 to my ip address
so the problem is i don't want to change my router to static ip address
as i want to port forward my routers with both are DHCP
is there a solution for it ?

or any other method i can use and it's easy to do ?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I understand that your setup looks like this:

```
    (------)        +----------+       +----------+        +-----+
  ( external )------| Router 1 |-------| Router 2 |--------| You |
   ( network)     a +----------+ b   c +----------+ d    e +-----+
     (-----)
```

Router 1 connects to the external network and gets its IP address (a) from the external network provider via DHCP. On router 1, you have port forwarding for port xxx on router 1 (a) to router 2, port yyy, IP address c.  And on router 2, you have port forwarding from IP address c, port yyy to IP address e, port zzz. Note that xxx, yyy and zzz can be the same port number.

The problem that you have is that R1 needs to know the IP address (c) of router 2, otherwise R1 does not know where to forward to. You have given R2 a static IP address, that you used on R1 for the port forwarding.

I assume, that these are normal consumer-grade routers. That means that the port forwarding rule must have a fixed IP address. You can either assign that address statically (as you have done) or make DHCP reservations  (in your case: probably the DHCP-server in R1). You will need to know the MAC-ID for interface c on R2. That would be somewhere under advanced-lansetup or advanced-dhcpsettings or something like that.

Note that the same applies to your network on your side of R2 (d and e). R2 needs to know the IP address e for the port forwarding rule in R2. And here too, you can make DHCP reservations.